# Is There a Difference Between Taxonomies and Categories?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, tags, terms, post-formats

I've been reading the codex for WordPress closely and am confused about the vague definitions between what a Taxonomy is and what a Category is. For that matter, term is also a word that is used in the description of Taxonomies, but seems used in a manner that hints that it isn't solely limited to a Taxonomy.

Both are described as a way to classify and group together posts. I do understand that Taxonomies are a more general form of categories, but how exactly do they relate to each other?

Is there a subtle difference I'm just not picking up on?

Comment: I think you should create custom taxonomies for custom post types rather than use the native categories so its less confusing.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Taxonomies, as previously described are a collective noun for the following

- `category`
- `post_tag`
- `post_format`
- `link_category`
- custom taxonomy

The first four are built-in taxonomies, while custom taxonomies are taxonomies that are manually created by the user with [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). Custom Taxonomies can be hierarchical (like the build-in taxonomy `category`) or not (like post tags)

The categories and tags that you create in the back end under the 'Posts' screen are in actual fact terms of the taxonomies `category` and `post_tag`

You cannot create extra terms in [`post_format`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats). `post_format` has built-in terms like `post_format_video`, `post_format_gallery` etc. See the codex for all post formats included

[image]

**EDIT**

I have updated the [Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) page in the codex to include my diagram and the missing `post_format` taxonomy

Comment: +1. Just a bit of pedantry: even built-in taxonomies are created via `register_taxonomy`. [2 times](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L205). :)

Comment: Jip, but they aren't manually created by the user. See your point though, I actually should have added that specific detail in my answer. :-) Many thanks

Comment: To be honest I added the comments to not miss the opportunity to tease WordPress about that stupid double registration of post types and taxonomies :D

Comment: Would be better if when you click the image @goose, it increases in size.

Comment: @G.M. hahaha, see the joke in all of this. It's like eating the same piece of meat twice

Answer (score 7):

Category, Tag, Link Category and Post Formats are built in taxonomies.

From [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

> Basically, a taxonomy is a way to group things together.
>
> The names for the different groupings in a taxonomy are called terms. Using groupings of animals as an example, we might call one group "birds", and another group "fish". "Fish" and "birds" are terms in our taxonomy. As an example from WordPress, a category or tag (see next section) is a term.

Answer (score 4):

`Category` is one of the built-in `taxonomy` in WordPress.

So to clear things: taxonomy is a way to group things together.

we can create custom taxonomies in WordPress just like built-in ones. For example `Cars`could be a taxonomy with `terms` like

```
Audi
Toyota
Benz
Mazda
```

there are mainly two types of taxonomies available which are `hierarchical` and `non hierarchical`

`Category` is best example of hierarchical taxonomy and `Tag` is an example of non hierarchical taxonomy