# Does WordPress Offer a Way to Find All of the Categories that Don't Have Children?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms

**Background**

As discussed in [Is There a Difference Between Taxonomies and Categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158206/), taxonomies refer to a generalized system of classification and organization of objects or data. In the case of WordPress; Categories, Tags, Post Format(ting), and Link Categories are built in taxonomies used to help classify and organize posts, links, and metadata. Terms are instances of these taxonomies; take for example a WordPress blog about computer software. If one of the taxonomies is a category, then one of the terms would be programming languages, because programming languages is a topic in computer software, and could be considered a categorical taxonomy. Additonally, WordPress developers and Plugin developers may utilize the `register_taxonomy()` function to initialize the built-in taxonomies, as well as *create new taxonomies* in WordPress.

**Working with WordPress Categories**

Ok, so WordPress offers up a few interesting functions under the [Taxonomy API](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php) ( no codex page, links to most recent source code ). If I understand them correctly, some of the promising functions I can use for my purposes are the following:

- `get_terms()`: The [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) pretty much says the same thing the source code comments say; that it retrieves the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies. I can provide an array of arguments to change which terms are returned; for example, to ensure that I include terms that are empty ( that is, are not referred to by any posts in the case of categories or tags ), I can set the *hide empty* argument to `0` or `false`;
- `get_term_heirarchy()`: Returns all of the term IDs of a given term's children as an array.
- `term_is_ancestor_of()`: Does just what it says; compare two terms, with term one being the term of reference, and term two the term to check for ancestry.

**Umm, So What About Descendants**

My goal here is to find out which categories don't have any child categories ( or descendant terms, to be more general ). I also don't want to ignore empty categories ( categories that have children but don't have any posts that reference them ).

Does WordPress have an easy way to do such a search? If so, are there performance concerns I should be worried about?

**Some Edits**: To provide an example for future reference, here is some hard data I am working with...

### WordPress Category Admin View

[image: Categories]

### Table of WordPress Taxonomy

[image: Table of WordPress Taxonomy]

### Table of WordPress Terms

[image: Table of WordPress Terms]

### Table of WordPress Term_Relationships

[image: Table of WordPress Term_Relationships]

In my test case, I want to return the following back:

- Uncategorized
- Firmware and Embedded Systems
- Operating Systems
- Web and Internet Based Applications
- Hardware

All of these have no children, even though some have an empty count.

Comment: These two lines are contradictory. `find out which categories don't have any child categories` and `But I want to make sure that I include categories that have descendants even if one of those descendants is empty in my search.` Please clarify what exactly you want.

Comment: My meaning of "empty" was ambiguous in the last part. What I was aiming for was to include categories that have descendants even though that category is "empty" in the sense that it doesn't have any posts that reference it ( no posts are classified under that category ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way easy way to do that. You have to query directly to achieve that. I am assuming, you only want the parent categories which don't have descendants or even if they have descendants, it's not used in any post

```
global $wpdb;
$categories = $wpdb->query("SELECT $wpdb->terms.* 
                            FROM  $wpdb->terms
                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy
                              ON $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id
                            WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id NOT IN(
                              SELECT $wpdb->term_taxonomy.parent
                              FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
                            )
                              AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'"
                          );
```

**Original Poster's Addon EDIT**

### How Does This Query Work?

Assume the table prefix is **main_**. First, we need to get all of the categories so we can start examining which ones have no children. This is done by selecting everything from the *term_taxonomy* table and using a `WHERE` clause to limit the results where the *taxonomy* field is equal to *category*:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM main_terms
WHERE main_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category';
```

However, we also need the names of the categories which is stored in the *terms* table, so we join the two tables together using an `INNER JOIN`, which also ensures that only rows of data common to both columns are included ( as [opposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) an outer join ). Both tables being joined together need a common column to "stitch" them together.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM main_term_taxonomy
INNER JOIN main_terms
ON main_term_taxonomy.term_id = main_terms.term_id
WHERE main_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category';
```

Finally, we exclude categories where they appear as a parent for another category in the *term_taxonomy* table. To do this, we use the keywords `NOT IN`, and construct another SQL query inside to `SELECT` everything in the *parent* column within *term_taxonomy*. This nested SQL query then provides which term ID's should be excluded from our results as they have entries in *term_taxonomy.parents*, indicating they are parents of another category.

```sql
SELECT main_term_taxonomy.* 
FROM  main_term_taxonomy
INNER JOIN main_terms
ON main_term_taxonomy.term_id = main_terms.term_id
WHERE main_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND main_term_taxonomy.term_id NOT IN(
    SELECT main_term_taxonomy.parent
    FROM main_term_taxonomy
);
```

Interestingly, this does return the correct rows, but doesn't include the category name. This is because we're selecting all of the columns from the wrong table, *main_term_taxonomy*. So we must switch the tables' places in our SQL to get the information we desire.

```sql
SELECT main_terms.* 
FROM  main_terms
INNER JOIN main_term_taxonomy
ON main_term_taxonomy.term_id = main_terms.term_id
WHERE main_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND main_term_taxonomy.term_id NOT IN(
    SELECT main_term_taxonomy.parent
    FROM main_term_taxonomy
);
```

Comment: No WordPress standard way to find categories that have no children? Well I'll be damned then!

Comment: @gate_engineer There is no wordpress function to fulfill your exact requirements.

Comment: The SQL doesn't return anything but Uncategorized back for me. I've edited my question for the data I am working with...

Comment: @gate_engineer That query was meant to find only the top level categories. Check out the edited version.

Comment: @gate_engineer Great job explaining the query. I believe you can construct queries like these on your own now. Everyone else who comes across these will also be able to see what's happening underneath.

Comment: @gate_engineer you should have posted that edit as a separate answer. Would have been more appropriate, and could potensially score yourself some reputation. :-)