# Export Posts in excel

Tags: excerpt

How can i export post only with this data in excel :-

Post title  -  Post URL  -  Author  - publish Date

Thanx

Comment: What had you tried? What are your development skills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have direct access to your WordPress database, you could use a tool like PHPMyAdmin or HeidiSQL to query the *post* and *user* tables and extract the information you need from the appropriate tables.

I discuss how an SQL query is constructed to get specific categories in [Does WordPress Offer A Way to Get only Child Categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158587/). You can probably construct your own query to get the needed information with some time.

Or, you could take the simple option and install something like [Export 2 Excel](http://wordpress.org/plugins/export-2-excel/).