# Breadcrumb not showing custom category post type

Tags: breadcrumb

I have an issue when it come to displaying the custom post type category in my breadcrumb menu on the page it looks something like the following

Home / / Post Title

*when it should be*

Home / Custom  Cat Name / Post Title

It shows the post on the page and the posts title but not the category?

Breadcrumb menu code:

```
            /*********************
            breadcrumbs menu
            *********************/
            function the_breadcrumb(){
                echo '<ul class="crumbs">';
                if (!is_home()){
                    echo '<li><a href="';
                    echo get_option('home');
                    echo '">';
                    echo 'Home';
                    echo '</a></li><li class="separator"> &#124; </li>';
                    if (is_category() || is_single('post')){
                        echo '<li>';
                        the_category(' </li><li class="separator"> &#124; </li><li> ');
                        if (is_single()){
                            echo '</li><li class="separator"> &#124; </li><li>';
                            the_title();
                            echo '</li>';
                        }
                    } elseif (is_page()){
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo the_title();
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                }
                elseif (is_tag()){
                    single_tag_title();
                }
                elseif (is_day()){
                    echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F jS, Y'); echo'</li>';
                }
                elseif (is_month()){
                    echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F, Y'); echo'</li>';
                }
                elseif (is_year()){
                    echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('Y'); echo'</li>';
                }
                elseif (is_author()){
                    echo"<li>Author Archive"; echo'</li>';
                }
                elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])){
                    echo "<li>Blog Archives"; echo'</li>';
                }
                elseif (is_search()){
                    echo"<li>Search Results"; echo'</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please properly intend your code, you making it very difficult for others who might be able to help you to read and keep track of your code

Comment: Sorry, edited it now

Comment: On a sidenote, I think `is_single('post')` should actually be `is_singular('post')` - [is_single() Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) and [is_singular() Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

Comment: Are you using build in categories or an custom taxonomy. See [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) Do you need to display the category/term assigned to the post in single view and/or do you need to show the category/taxonomy/term name on the category/taxonomy page

Comment: Just another thing, `the_category` won't work outside the loop. You should look at `get_the_category` instead

Comment: I'm using a custom category, also I shouldn't have used "is_single('post')){" that didn't do anything and unfortunately neither did get_the_category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not one hundred percent sure where and what needs to be displayed.

If you need to show the current single post's category, you'll need to use [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) in stead of [`the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) as `the_category` needs to be called inside the loop. You can use `get_the_category` as follow (*Remember to use the `global $post` to retrieve the post ID*)

```
<?php
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
var_dump($categories);
?>
```

If you need to get the category name on a category page, you can use `get_query_var('cat')` to retrieve info about the current category page.

Here is an example of the breadcrumbs that I use on my site.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'pietergoosen_breadcrumbs' ) ) :

    function pietergoosen_breadcrumbs() {
          /* === OPTIONS === */
        $text['home']     = _x( 'Home', 'Home', 'pietergoosen' ); // text for the 'Home' link
     $text['category'] = __( 'Archive by Category "%s"', 'pietergoosen' );  // text for a category page
     $text['search']   = __( 'Search Results for "%s" Query', 'pietergoosen' ); // text for a search results page
     $text['tag']      = __( 'Posts Tagged "%s"', 'pietergoosen' );  // text for a tag page
     $text['author']   = __( 'Posts Posted by %s', 'pietergoosen' ); // text for an author page
     $text['404']      = __( 'Error 404', 'pietergoosen' );  // text for the 404 page

     $show_current   = 1; // 1 - show current post/page/category title in breadcrumbs, 0 - don't show
     $show_on_home   = 0; // 1 - show breadcrumbs on the homepage, 0 - don't show
     $show_home_link = 1; // 1 - show the 'Home' link, 0 - don't show
     $show_title     = 1; // 1 - show the title for the links, 0 - don't show
     $delimiter      = ' &raquo; '; // delimiter between crumbs
     $before         = '<span class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
     $after          = '</span>'; // tag after the current crumb
     /* === END OF OPTIONS === */

     global $post;
        $here_text    = __('You are currently here! &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;', 'pietergoosen');
     $home_link    = home_url('/');
     $link_before  = '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">';
     $link_after   = '</span>';
     $link_attr    = ' rel="v:url" property="v:title"';
     $link         = $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr . ' href="%1$s">%2$s</a>' . $link_after;
        if (isset($post)){
            $parent_id    = $parent_id_2  = $post->post_parent;
        }
     $frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');

     if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {

            if ($show_on_home == 1) echo '<div class="breadcrumb"><a href="' . $home_link . '">' . $text['home'] . '</a></div>';

        } else {

         echo '<div class="breadcrumb">';
         if ($show_home_link == 1) {
             echo  $here_text . '<a href="' . $home_link . '" rel="v:url" property="v:title">' . $text['home'] . '</a>';
             if ($frontpage_id == 0 || $parent_id != $frontpage_id) echo $delimiter;
         }

         if ( is_category() ) {
             $this_cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
             if ($this_cat->parent != 0) {
                 $cats = get_category_parents($this_cat->parent, TRUE, $delimiter);
                 if ($show_current == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$delimiter$#", "$1", $cats);
                 $cats = str_replace('<a', $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr, $cats);
                 $cats = str_replace('</a>', '</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
                 if ($show_title == 0) $cats = preg_replace('/ title="(.*?)"/', '', $cats);
                 echo $cats;
             }
                if ($show_current == 1) echo $before . sprintf($text['category'], single_cat_title('', false)) . $after;

          } elseif ( is_search() ) {
              echo $before . sprintf($text['search'], get_search_query()) . $after;

          } elseif ( is_day() ) {
             echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y')) . $delimiter;
             echo sprintf($link, get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')), get_the_time('F')) . $delimiter;
             echo $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;

         } elseif ( is_month() ) {
             echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y')) . $delimiter;
             echo $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;

          } elseif ( is_year() ) {
              echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;

          } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
                if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
                    $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
                    $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
                    printf($link, $home_link . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/', $post_type->labels->singular_name);
                    if ($show_current == 1) echo $delimiter . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
                } else {
                    $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
                    $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $delimiter);
                    if ($show_current == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$delimiter$#", "$1", $cats);
                    $cats = str_replace('<a', $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr, $cats);
                    $cats = str_replace('</a>', '</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
                    if ($show_title == 0) $cats = preg_replace('/ title="(.*?)"/', '', $cats);
                    echo $cats;
                    if ($show_current == 1) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
                }

         } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
             $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
             echo $before . $post_type->labels->singular_name . $after;

         } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
               $parent = get_post($parent_id);
                $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
                $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $delimiter);
                $cats = str_replace('<a', $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr, $cats);
                $cats = str_replace('</a>', '</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
                if ($show_title == 0) $cats = preg_replace('/ title="(.*?)"/', '', $cats);
                echo $cats;
              printf($link, get_permalink($parent), $parent->post_title);
              if ($show_current == 1) echo $delimiter . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

            } elseif ( is_page() && !$parent_id ) {
                if ($show_current == 1) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

            } elseif ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
                if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
                    $breadcrumbs = array();
                    while ($parent_id) {
                        $page = get_page($parent_id);
                        if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
                            $breadcrumbs[] = sprintf($link, get_permalink($page->ID), get_the_title($page->ID));
                        }
                        $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
                    }
                   $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
                   for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumbs); $i++) {
                       echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
                       if ($i != count($breadcrumbs)-1) echo $delimiter;
                   }
              }
             if ($show_current == 1) {
                 if ($show_home_link == 1 || ($parent_id_2 != 0 && $parent_id_2 != $frontpage_id)) echo $delimiter;
                 echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
             }

          } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
             echo $before . sprintf($text['tag'], single_tag_title('', false)) . $after;

          } elseif ( is_author() ) {
               global $author;
               $userdata = get_userdata($author);
              echo $before . sprintf($text['author'], $userdata->display_name) . $after;

           } elseif ( is_404() ) {
               echo $before . $text['404'] . $after;
           }

          if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
              if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
             echo __('&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp; Page', 'pietergoosen') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');
             if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
         }

           echo '</div><!-- .breadcrumbs -->';

        }
    }

endif;
```

*NOTE: I've copied this function from somewhere a year or two ago without adding author credit (bad me), so I can't remember who the original author was. If you, the author, see this post, please reply so that I can add full credit to you*)