# Post archive for certain post format

Tags: wp-query, archives, post-formats

I am using the following code for a custom archive of all posts:

```
$taxonomy = 'category';
$param_type = 'category__in';
$term_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
if ($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $args = array(
            "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  ?>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><?php echo $term->name;?></h3>
            <?php
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <ul style="list-style-type: circle;">
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                </ul>
            <?php 
            endwhile;
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
```

Now this pulls all posts, but is there a way to limit the results to only a certain post format?

Same for this:

```
echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts 
    WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. If you haven't done so, please take your time and visit our [tour] page. I just want to make sure, your looking to just retrieve posts from a specific post format under each term

Answer (score 1):

[Post formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) are actually terms of the [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) `post_format`. I have done a post about this what taxonomies are and their hierarchies which you can check out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545)

To get a list of all terms under the taxonomy `post_format`, simply use [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) and `var_dump()` the result

```
$terms = get_terms('post_format','hide_empty=0');
  ?><pre><?php var_dump($terms); ?></pre><?php
```

This will print

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#207 (9) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    string(3) "142"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Aside"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(17) "post-format-aside"
    ["term_group"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    string(3) "142"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "post_format"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#310 (9) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    string(3) "129"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Audio"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(17) "post-format-audio"
    ["term_group"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    string(3) "129"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "post_format"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#309 (9) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    string(3) "105"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Gallery"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(19) "post-format-gallery"
    ["term_group"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    string(3) "105"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "post_format"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#308 (9) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    string(3) "128"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Quote"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(17) "post-format-quote"
    ["term_group"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    string(3) "128"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "post_format"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#307 (9) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    string(3) "106"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Video"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(17) "post-format-video"
    ["term_group"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    string(3) "106"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "post_format"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

One thing though that I want to highlight, `standard` is **not** a post format, which is a let down. Any post without a designated post format should actually be assigned a post format default. The problem is, if you need only posts that don't have a special post format, you need to run a `tax_query` and exclude all posts that does have a post format.

So, to get posts from a certain post format, you can run a `tax_query` with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Example to get all posts from video post format:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'post-format-video',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you need to get posts without any post format attached, you'll need to do something like

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('post-format-video',' post-format-quote', 'post-format-gallery', 'post-format-audio', 'post-format-aside' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a taxonomy argument to specify the post type in your WP_Query. Here's an example straight from codex:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote' ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You need to replace `post-format-quote` with the one you need.