# Get taxonomy names by post id

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm trying to create a single page where I display a few posts on one page. So far so good. Works all fine. Now I display posts in a foreach loop where I check if they are connnected to the page.

What I need ist something like `wp_get_post_terms($post->ID);` but that doens't work. There are `custom registered_taxonomy`'s.

So how can I get all `taxonomy names` by `$post->ID`?

Comment: So, you don't need to get a list of terms, but a list of the taxonomies these terms belongs to that are attached to the post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ooh, thank's for the advices and help (Robert + Peter). The Term confused myself :) This worked for me:

```
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies('','names');
wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomies,  array("fields" => "names"));
```

Comment: You should check out my answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) about taxonomies. This should help you understand which is what. Remember to accept your own answer

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks for your comment and link to that answer!

Answer (score 8):

For any custom post type you can easily get the current post's taxonomies list. Copy and paste the following code:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : the_post();  
    $post_type = get_post_type(get_the_ID());   
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);   
    $taxonomy_names = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), $taxonomies,  array("fields" => "names")); 
    if(!empty($taxonomy_names)) :
       foreach($taxonomy_names as $tax_name) : ?>              
          <p><?php echo $tax_name; ?> </p>
       <?php endforeach;
    endif;
endif;  ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `get_the_term_list`

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'taxonomy', '', ', ' ); ?>
```

You can use this in loop. Also, change taxonomy in above code with yours.

Comment: gives an error: `object(WP_Error)#2386 (2) {
  ["errors":"WP_Error":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["invalid_taxonomy"]=>...`

Comment: You will need to change `Name of the taxonomy` in above code.

Comment: There are a few taxonomy names, and that's what I try to find out what their names are..

Comment: Great solution! Simple and clean!

Answer (score 1):

```
$term_list = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'your_taxonomy');
$types ='';
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
     $types .= ucfirst($term_single->slug).', ';
}
$typesz = rtrim($types, ', ');
echo $typesz;
```