# Conditional tag for all categories of a custom post type

Tags: conditional-tags, pre-get-posts

I need a conditional tag which returns true on all categories added to a specific custom post type.

Tried dozens of variations using the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) from the Codex but still stuck.

What i'm trying to do is order all posts in all categories added to the CPT in ASC order by title.

This is what i'm using for the CPT archives which works:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpsites_cpt_loop_filter');

function wpsites_cpt_loop_filter($query) {
  if (
    ! is_admin()
    && $query->is_main_query
    && is_post_type_archive( array( 'sarasota-condos', 'sarasota-homes' ) )
    || is_post_type_archive( array( 'neighborhoods', 'condominiums' ) )
  ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  }
}
```

Edit: Here's the code which is used to create the categories for the CPT

```
// Create "Neighborhoods" CPT category taxonomy
add_action( 'init', 'my_type_taxonomy2' );
function my_type_taxonomy2() {

    register_taxonomy( 'sarasota-homes', 'neighborhoods',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          => _x( 'Neighborhood Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'executive' ),
                'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Neighborhood Category', 'executive' ),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Neigborhood Category', 'executive' ),
            ),
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'hierarchical'        => true,
            //'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'equipment-type', 'with_front' => false ),
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_tagcloud'       => false,
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: I've lost you somewhere. Do you need to sort posts on your cpt archive pages by category and then within each category sort by title?

Comment: Just need to order posts by title within each category archive page for each CPT. I know i could use a conditional for all categories but i only want to alter the CPT categories.

Comment: These categories, are they custom taxonomies or build in categories, and are they shared with `post` post type?

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) I have done. It is confusing if you don't use the correct terms. You are using a custom taxonomy. And also, if you read my posts, you should see not to use hyphens in custom taxonomy and custom post type names :-)

Comment: Agree, not my code and i wouldn't write it that way either. I tried is_tax but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few concerns here in the registration of your custom taxonomy

- as from the comments on your OP, this is not your code, but a client's code. Still, taxonomy and custom post type names should never contain hyphens, just underscores to separate words
- there are non valid arguments used like `exclude_from_search` and `has_archive` which doesn't exists `register_taxonomy`
- this is just a tip, set the `query_var` argument to true to make the use of working directly with the query variables available for the taxonomy

The conditional tag, [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax)should return true on any taxonomy archive page. You can also make this tag very specific by setting its parameters.

I do believe that this is rather a logic problem than a Wordpress problem. I would however first correct the problems that I have mentioned above. You should try to separate your concerns here.

I would recommend to first test all conditions separately and make sure that individualy they work, and then work from there putting everything together. I would also not mix the `&&` and `||` operators, try to separate them.

One last thing to make sure of, make sure that there are no custom queries that have replaced the main query on the archive pages. Your changes won't be applied if a custom query is used.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about the commenting out of the rewrite rule and the way they've registered the taxonomies in the CPT?

Comment: Apart from the problems I've highlighted, everything looks OK. Rewrites aren't my thing TBH, I really must invest time and dig into rewrites :-). Do you have an idea that the problem is caused by rewrites. Have you tested this

Comment: For interest sake, where you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No but thanks for your efforts @goose. I'll give you the points as i know its a problem with the clients coding.

Comment: Always tough trying to sort out someone else's mess. Hope you getting well paid for that :-)