# WP_Query by a category id and a custom post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query

I need to query all posts that belong to a given category (default, not custom) and a custom post type. As simple as that. The fact that it doesn't work, to me, is ridiculous. Unless I'm missing something?

Here's what I've tried:

```
$args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 50, 
    //'taxonomy' => 'category',      
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_type'
    'category__in' => array($cat_id),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

then

```
$args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 50,    
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_type'
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $cat_id,
        ),
    ),
 );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and of course

```
$args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 50, 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_type'
    'category' => $cat_id,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

also, some combinations of adding/renaming/removing the `$args` keys.

Getting all posts by a post type and then looping through them and filtering by a category is not an effective option, I believe.

Please help.

Comment: similar but not helpful: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166564/category-in-not-working-on-custom-post-type

Comment: well your first one has a typo. I assume you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and aren't seeing any errors? where do you set `$cat_id`? you can `var_dump` your query after and look at the generated SQL, it should reveal the issue. also, you probably shouldn't be overwriting `$wp_query`.

Comment: @Milo thanks ok the `$cat_id` is actually an array key (this is where the single quote came from), I've just edited it to be a simple variable so this question looks less messy. Thanks for pointing out though. As for not overwriting the `$wp_query` - I'll keep that in mind, thanks

Comment: Still appear to be syntax errors there Jamaica. Missing comma in your array should throw a PHP parse error.  Can you post the actual code you're using w/o edits?

Comment: @jdm2112 Shame on me, that was the comma. This explains why I was getting nothing when trying to uncomment the category-related keys. I would ask you to post the suggestion as an answer so I can accept and upvote, but I am not sure if this will be useful for the community. I've upvoted your other answers instead. I will delete this question a bit later. Thank you

Comment: Glad that solved it for you.

Answer (score 15):

try this, it's work for me.

```
    $args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 50, 
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_type'
    'cat' => $cat_id,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Category Parameters**

```
cat (int): use category id.
category_name (string): use category slug (NOT name).
category__and (array): use category id.
category__in (array): use category id.
category__not_in (array): use category id.
```

Comment: Hi @kunal-gauswami, welcome to the site and thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I don't have the code anymore so I can't try your suggestion, but if someone confirms that it worked, I will happily accept the answer. Here's an upvote from me anyway.

Answer (score 9):

this worked for me.

```
$args=array(
'posts_per_page' => 50,    
'post_type' => 'my_custom_type'
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category', //double check your taxonomy name in you dd 
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $cat_id,
    ),
   ),
 );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: This answer is correct if you are doing a query for a custom taxonomy linked to the custom post type

Answer (score 0):

Get posts by category id

```
$categories = get_categories();
$loop = new WP_Query([
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $categories[0]->term_id
        ],
    ],
]);
```