# Get Categories & Posts With Type Article

Tags: posts, categories

I want to fetch all categories and the post that belongs to the category, to fetch all categories, I am using the following code

```
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'article-category',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'parent'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    'child_of'      => 0
);
$get_categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
```

To fetch all post with type articles I am using this code

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
));
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
}
```

This gives me the list of all categories and list of all post of type articles in a separate loop, however what I want is something in this line

```
Category 1
    - Post 1 Title
    - Post 2 Title
    - Post 3 Title
Category 2
    - Post 4 Title
    - Post 5 Title
    - Post 6 Title
    - Post 7 Title
    ...
...
```

I am basically trying to fetch all categories and all post of type article that belongs to this category, I tried many different ways, but nothing seems to work out, how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try by the tax_query. [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166564/category-in-not-working-on-custom-post-type) questions answer can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with following code:

```
$currentCategoryId = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'article-category', array('fields' => 'ids'));
if (is_array($currentCategoryId) && !empty($currentCategoryId[0])) {
    $currentCategoryId = (int)$currentCategoryId[0];
}

$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'article-category',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'parent'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    'child_of'      => 0
);
$get_categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
$categories = array();
foreach ($get_categories as $index => $category) {
    $categories[$index]['id'] = $category->cat_ID;
    $categories[$index]['slug'] = $category->slug;
    $categories[$index]['name'] = $category->name;
}
$articles = array();
foreach ($categories as $index => $category) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'article',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'article-category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category['slug'],
            )
        )
    );
    $articles[$index]['category']['id'] = $category['id'];
    $articles[$index]['category']['name'] = $category['name'];
    $articles[$index]['category']['slug'] = $category['slug'];
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($posts_array as $key => $_post) {
        $articles[$index]['posts'][$key]['id'] = $_post->ID;
        $articles[$index]['posts'][$key]['title'] = $_post->post_title;
        $articles[$index]['posts'][$key]['permalink'] = get_permalink($_post->ID);
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```