# Adding a button to a product if it's in a category, then linking to that category

Tags: categories, buttons

I've got a site with products... and some of those products are in categories (collections). For those products I want to show a button 'view the collection,' and have that link to the category.

So, I did this:

```
<?php if(in_category): ?>
<a class="btn-light" href="http://dev.andriannashamarisinc.com/product-category/<?php get_the_category( $id ); ?>">View The Entire Collection</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And, it definitely puts the button on the specific products, but then the link isn't
going to the specific category that I want.

What's the correct snippet for this?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. To start you of and learn how the site operates, please visit [ask] and take a [tour] :-)

Comment: Product must be a custom post type, and Category you refer is Taxonomy (Collections). You can not use in_category() here, its for regular posts.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

From your comments, you are using [`get_cat_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID) totally wrong. You can only feed one category to it. Please follow all links given and check the examples in the codex. Also, as stated, enable debugging, because that is all problems you should have picked up

Secondly, it seems that you are using a custom taxonomy and not the build in category structure, in which case, none of the suggestions in my original answer will work. Please check out [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) I've done on what the difference is between categories and custom taxonomies

I don't have time to code now (I also don't really understand what exactly you want), but here are links you should check out from the codex and follow the examples given on these pages.

- [`wp_get_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)
- [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link)
- [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I don't believe that your code worked at all. You have a couple of errors here

Before I step right into the errors, please see [Debugging_in_WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) as most problems should have been solved with debug turned on

Now, for the errors

- You need to specify a category when working with [`in_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

> **$category**
>
> (mixed) (required) One or more categories specified by ID (integer), name or slug (string), or an array of these
>
> Default: None

- Never hardcode any URL's into a theme or plugin. Make use of relative or absolute paths where appropriate. The problem with hardcoding is that a theme or plugin cannot be used on other domains by default
- When you are using [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category), you actually have to set a value for `$id`. Just simply adding `$id` will result in an undefined variable notice. You can either leave it blank, supply an actual post ID or use `$post->ID` to use the current post ID (which is the default btw, so no need to do that, just leave it blank)
- To get the URL (link) to a category page, make use of [`get_category_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)

You can probably try something in the line of: (Samples from the codex)

```
if( in_category( 'ID, name or slug of the category' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
   // Get the ID of a given category
   $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

   // Get the URL of this category
   $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>

<?php
}else{
    //displays nothing
}
```

Comment: `    <?php if( in_category( 'triple-burnt, cracked-resin, st-barts, high-quality-petrified-wood' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
   // Get the ID of a given category
   $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'cracked resin, triple burnt, st barts, high quality petrified wood' );

   // Get the URL of this category
   $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>

<?php
}else{
    //displays nothing
} ?>`

Comment: Well... not posting the code correctly in here, but anyway I'm attempting to use what you've laid out here, but am not getting it. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please see my update. Also , rather file an edit to your question and add your code there. Don't add code in the comments section, it is totally unreadable

Answer (score -1):

You check if Product is associated with any Collection or not.

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'collections', array("fields" => "all"));
```

Returns an array of All term Items for taxonomy "collections".

IF $term_list has values you can display collection(s) using a loop

```
$name =  $term_list->name;
$link =  $term_list->link;
```

Comment: Drop in a reason for -ve vote please. Would be nice to know where I got wrong.