# Custom taxonomy applied to links

Tags: custom-taxonomy, links

is it possible to apply a custom taxonomy to links? if so how?

i already did this, but it does not seem to work:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Lessons', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Lesson', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Lesson Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( '', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( '', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add new Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Lessons with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'has_archive'                => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'lesson', array( 'post','portfolio','link', 'forum' ), $args );
```

thanks

Marco

Comment: The correct taxonomy is `link_category`, not just `link`. See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Link Manager is a pseudo post type at best.  You can either use the default 'Categories', or go full circle and (1) register a new post type + the custom taxonomy on the new post type or (2) use post formats + the custom taxonomy on posts

[Links Manager](http://codex.wordpress.org/Links_Manager)

[Registering a new Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

[Post Formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats)

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for the link to be assimilated to a post-type.