# What is actually taxonomy in wordpress?

Tags: taxonomy

What is actually taxonomy in wordpress? How and where exactly I can use taxonomy. I have read many google search about it but need someone to just explain in little simple language.

Comment: Did you see [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545)

Comment: I find [database descriptions/diagrams](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) to be an excellent tool for understanding base level questions for any application, regardless of scope or language.