# Custom Taxonomy Query by Taxonomny not working

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

Not sure what's going on - here's a look at my code:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'show_posts' => '-1', 
    'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
    'cat' => $goalsCat->cat_ID,
    'post_type' => 'Goals',
    'author' => $current_user_id,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$wp_query_assigned = new WP_Query($args); 


if ( $wp_query_assigned->have_posts() ) : 

    while ($wp_query_assigned->have_posts()) : $wp_query_assigned->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        echo '<p>'.$title.'</p>';
   endwhile;
else : 

    echo '<p>You have no set Goals';

endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

If I remove the category param from the $args array, it returns all the posts in the category, so I know that this part is working correctly. But when I add the category, it returns nothing. I am able to confirm that there are posts in each category and that all the ID's are correct.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So, the problem is orderby as the title suggests or with the category param? Can you show us what is `$goalsCat` object or at least the value of `$goalsCat->cat_ID`? Also, you have a typo in your code: `orderly` should be `orderby`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I fixed the typo on 'orderby'. $goalsCat->cat_ID returns the id of the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here looking at your code and tags used to tag your question

- `show_posts` is wrong. It is depreciated in favor of `posts_per_page`. Also, it should be `showposts`.
- You cannot use `showposts` and `posts_per_page` together. You should only use `posts_per_page`
- Don't use camelcase in you custom post type names, they are really problematic when it comes to templates. Only use underscores and lowercase letters. The same goes for custom taxonomies
- I do believe you are using a custom taxonomy and not build-in categories, which is the number one suspect failing your code. The category parameters does not work with custom taxonomies, you should use a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). But first, [read this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) to learn what a category is and what a term and taxonomy is

Comment: Awesome - it's been a bit since I've been in WP dev mode. Totally forgot about the tax_query stuff and the differences in WP between all the different cats and taxonomies. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped. Enjoy :-)