# Category Template for Custom Post Type

Tags: categories

I'm driving myself crazy with the following issue, hope you can help me!

I'm working on a WordPress theme for a business directory so I decided to make some custom posts types on functions.php file like "Surgical", "Non Surgical", etc... Under the custom post type of "surgical" I've created a custom taxonomy called "surgical_cat". Everything is ok until now.

The thing is that I've created some categories under "surgical_cat" called "Arm Lift", "Brachioplasty reduction", “Breast Augmentation” and I made template according to the codex rule: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates but it didn't work. I have been looking around like crazy and nothing showed up... except 404.php error page/template.

Can someone please let me know how to proceed to make this category based template for my category inside this custom taxonomy? I am really worried about this :(
Thank you very much!

To see the site, please visit that link: http://my-portfolio-site.site88.net/business_directory/

You could find the list under the title: Procedures Surgical

CUSTOM POST TYPE REGISTERING FOR 'surgical' on functions.php file:

```
// CUSTOM POST TYPE REGISTERING FOR 'surgical'
add_action( 'init', 'surgical_post' );
function surgical_post() {
        register_post_type( 'surgical',
                array(
                'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __( 'Surgical' ),
                        'singular_name' => __( 'Surgical' ),
                        'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
                        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Surgical' ),
                        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Surgical' ),
                        'new_item' => __( 'New Surgical' ),
                        'view_item' => __( 'View Surgical' ),
                        'not_found' => __( 'Sorry, we couldn\'t find the Surgical you are looking for.' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => true,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'capability_type' => 'page',
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'surgical' ),
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', )
                )
        );
}
```

REGISTERING CUSTOM TAXONOMY FOR CUSTOM POST TYPE 'surgical' on functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'business_listing_taxonomy');
function business_listing_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'surgical_cat',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces).
        'surgical',  //post type name
        array(
        'public'                => true,
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'label'                 => 'Surgical Category',  //Display name
        'query_var'             => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'rewrite'               => array(
            'slug'              => 'surgical', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front'        => false // Don't display the category base before
            )
        )
    );
}
```

wp list categories for displaying categories on homepage:

```
    //list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'     => 'surgical',
  'taxonomy'     => 'surgical_cat',
  'orderby'      => 'surgical_order',
  'show_count'   => 1,
  'pad_counts'   => 1,
  'hierarchical' => 1,
  'title_li'     => '',
  );
?>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean about this statement, "I need these categories to have an specific look, different than the index or category template and I can't make it."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a taxonomy template, not a category. I suspect that you have misunderstanding about categories, terms and custom taxonomies. I would suggest that you read my post on this particular subject [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545)

Study the taxonomy template hierarchy in the linked page in your question

As for the 404 page, you most probably haven't flushed your permalinks after adding your custom post type.

### EDIT

I have missed the fact that your rewrites for both your custom post type and taxonomy is the same, which will 404 all taxonomy requests. Have a look at [this recent post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/175712/31545), it has a work around if you want to keep your slugs the same.

Here is the solution reposted by @JeremyLove. Change the code as needed and with your taxonomy and post type names. Also, **important**, flush your permalinks after making any changes to your code so that the new structures can be saved

```
function taxonomy_slug_rewrite($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();
    // get all custom taxonomies
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies(array('_builtin' => false), 'objects');
    // get all custom post types
    $post_types = get_post_types(array('public' => true, '_builtin' => false), 'objects');

    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {

            // go through all post types which this taxonomy is assigned to
            foreach ($taxonomy->object_type as $object_type) {

                // check if taxonomy is registered for this custom type
                if ($object_type == $post_type->rewrite['slug']) {

                    // get category objects
                    $terms = get_categories(array('type' => $object_type, 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name, 'hide_empty' => 0));

                    // make rules
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        $rules[$object_type . '/' . $term->slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?' . $term->taxonomy . '=' . $term->slug;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // merge with global rules
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'taxonomy_slug_rewrite');
```

Comment: Hi @Pieter Goosen, thanks for your reply. According to your advice, I have created a template called **taxonomy-surgical_cat-arm-lift.php** where **surgical_cat** is custom taxonomy for post and **arm-lift** is term of that custom taxonomy. Then I flushed my permalinks after adding my custom post type using that code [flush rules on theme activation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules), but still it doesn't work. Do you have any advice? Keep well.

Comment: Please see my update, this should solve your issue