# Custom term templates

Tags: terms, template-hierarchy

So, I did some research online but could not find a solid answer, so here I am.

I am in need to make a custom woocommerce category page for a specific category.

For example, I have a category called "Awesome".

Instead of using a regular category page, generated by a shortcode`[product_category category="something"]`, I want to customized a specific category page for `Awesome`.

I found that I need to edit the `taxonomy-product_cat.php` file but I have no idea how to link it to the specific category called `awesome`.

In other words, I am thinking of making a custom copy of the php file then add it as a theme `template`.

Does anyone know how I can achieve it?

Comment: To the close voters. Since when is the template hierarchy off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), you need to create a template `taxonomy-{$taxonomy}-{$term}.php`. In your case, that template will be called `taxonomy-product_cat-awesome.php` where I assumed the **slug** of your term is `awesome`

Just a tip, the "categories" of a custom taxonomy is called `terms`. The build in taxonomy `category` "categories" is also called terms, but we call them in plain language categories. To understand this, you should check out [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545)

Comment: Thank you Pieter. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Glad your issue is solved. Enjoy :-)