# expire wordpress user posts

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I'm trying to make classified WordPress theme and I need to make users posts expire date plus show that date into the post.
Users only allowed to publish their posts in post-types not as ordinary WordPress posts.

Does anyone know how can i make it?

**Update:**
According to the answers given to this question till now I have to say giving expire date to the post types by meta post is not what I want cause users could change that I want the 30 days date (means 30 days after publish their post) the post permanently be deleted and the date automatically add to the post in back-end not manually with admin or author.
Hope my mean be more clear now.

Special thanks to: @sakibmoon .
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when a post "expires"?

Comment: be delete or going to draft no matter just not appear in website anymore

Answer (score 6):

You can set the expire date as post meta value. In `single.php` you can easily show that date by querying the post meta.

See [update_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) and [get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Now, the second part of your question is pretty tricky. I can think of 2 solutions.

- **Cron**

You can use wordpress cron to run at a time interval to check which post has been expired and delete/set as `draft`/whatever you wan't to do with those posts. See [wp_cron()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron)

**Pros:**

1. Very easy to implement.

**Cons:**

1. The cron task won't fire, if no one visit your site.(For busy site with frequent user, this is not a issue)
2. If you have lots of post, checking every post at a time interval will have performance penalty.
3. Not reliable at all. The post will not expire exactly at the time specified.

( I have always hated wp_cron() and never use it myself)

A little bit better option is to use cron task from your server. But even this won't ensure post expiry at exact time as you have to run cron at a time interval and also there is performance penalty.

- **Modify Single.php file and Post Query**

A better option in my opinion is to check post expiry date in your `single.php` and display a message checking expiration_date. You can also delete/set as `draft`, first time this page is requested by a user after the expiration date causing 404 for further visit.

To remove the expired pages from archive pages, you can use [pre_get_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook to modify the query based on the post meta.

**Pros**

1. Exact expiration date.
2. Total control over what you want to do.
3. Negligible performance penalty.

**Cons:**

1. Just a little bit more work.

(Considering the advantages, it's not that much of more work. If I were you, I would choose this option)

- **Use a Plugin**

There are lots of [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=post%20expiration) that seems to do this exactly. But I don't know how they work or whether they can fulfill your requirements. You have to check these yourself.

**EDIT**

> I'm trying to make classified WordPress theme and I need to make users posts expire date plus show that date into the post. Users only allowed to publish their posts in post-types not as ordinary WordPress posts.

You have to use [register_post_type()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) to create custom post type. You will also need to create custom taxonomy if you want to categories them. Use [register_taxonomy()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for that.

Also see [Is There a Difference Between Taxonomies and Categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158206/is-there-a-difference-between-taxonomies-and-categories/)

> According to the answers given to this question till now I have to say giving expire date to the post types by meta post is not what I want cause users could change that I want the 30 days date (means 30 days after publish their post) the post permanently be deleted and the date automatically add to the post in back-end not manually with admin or author.

Here's what you are wrong. Saving post meta isn't done by back end. How you are going to create and update post meta is up to you. For your case, it will be best to use [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action hook and update the `expire_date` from there. A sample example would be

```
//This hook will fire when a post is created or updated.
add_action('save_post', 'set_expire_date_meta')

function set_expire_date_meta( $post_id ) {
    //We are checking if the saved post belongs to the CPT
    if( 'custom-post-type-name-that-you-registered' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        $meta = $get_post_meta($post_id, 'expire_date', true);
        //If the meta already exists, the post is being updated and we don't need to save the meta again
        if( $meta == '' ) {
            $timestamp_30day = strtotime("+1 month");
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'expire_date', $timestamp_30day);
        }
    }
}
```

As you want the expiry date to work for the custom post type only, add an extra condition on main query like `is_post_type_archive( 'custom-post-type-name-that-you-registered' )` in `remove_expired_post_from_main_query` function that I mentioned so that main query won't be altered for any other post type like post/page etc.

In `expire_posts_to_404_redirect`, change `is_single()` to `is_singular('custom-post-type-name-that-you-registered')` so that only these custom post type will go to 404.

```
//This filter will show 404 page for expired posts for the cpt that you registered
add_filter('template_redirect', 'expire_posts_to_404_redirect' );
function expire_posts_to_404_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    global $post;

    if( is_singular('custom-post-type-name-that-you-registered') ) {
        $expire_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expire_date', true);
        if( ($expire_date != '') && ($expire_date < time()) ) {
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header( 404 );
        }
    }
}

//This action will alter main query to remove expired posts from archive pages of the CPT that you registered
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'remove_expired_post_from_main_query');
function remove_expired_post_from_main_query($query) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('custom-post-type-name-that-you-registered') ) {
        //We are comparing expiry date with current timestamp.
        //It will only keep the posts with expiry_date > current timestamp
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'expire_date',
                'value' => time(),
                'compare' => '>'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot now I'm lighting about the solution but can you give an example of your second opinion please? so maybe I can edit it to what i want?

Comment: @ScottWolter I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much i going to test this code. Can I use this code in my plugin function page? cause for making post-type I'm using plugin.

Comment: @ScottWolter I've further edited my code. If you have any more questions let me know. If this solves your issue, accept the answer.

Comment: your second code will bring my site into error page! says this line of code has problem:  `if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) ) {` while i want log in.  1- in your code second part has one `)` more (after delete that still has error) 2- this is screenshot of my error http://postimg.org/image/f7gh3n44r/

Comment: @ScottWolter you have to pass `$query` as argument for `pre_get_posts`. I've added that. Try now.

Comment: All my website (no matter what page) when I open show me 404 page now!

Comment: @ScottWolter It works perfectly. I've checked this time. Are there any post with `expire_date` set and which hasn't expired? It not, you won't get any posts. If you want to exclude home page, you can set `!is_home()` condition in `pre_get_posts` function. For archive page only, set `is_archive()` and so on.

Comment: I've installed WordPress on local host for test my theme and there is some posts I've published for test. when I use this code my site going to show just 404 page for all pages. My posts now no have any expire date cause this I asked for some codes to give them expire date and try. And honestly about this part of your code I'm confuse `'key' => 'expire_date',` that I have to replace with number of dates or just leave it like that! Sorry I'm not that bad In WordPress but this code is new for me.

Comment: @ScottWolter For understanding that you should search for how to formulate meta_query. That part ensure that only posts with an `expire_date` meta field set and `expire_date` having `TIMESTAMP` value greater than current time will be returned. The rest of the posts will go to 404 page. You should comment this code and then create some posts with post meta `expire_date` with appropriate value(like 1527258369 which is a timestamp value of May 25, 2018) and then check your site with this code.

Comment: I really appreciate @sakibmoon But I think even if this code works for me could be one problem, and that is if i set expire_date by meta field means after i let users posts be published they can edit their post and change the expire date! or even worse they can totally delete expire_date! and of course when my website for example has 2000 posts by users can not every day check one one to find which post has changed by users. Understand me?

Comment: @ScottWolter How do you want to set the `expire_date` and whether users get to edit them or not is totally up to you. If you can post your detailed scenario of what you are trying to achieve, that might help to clarify. You should edit: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/188935/edit your answer or better yet ask a separate question of what you are trying to achieve and what problems you are facing.

Comment: I've updated my question thanks a lot for all your helps.

Comment: @ScottWolter see the edit.