# Multiple Post Status

Tags: post-status

How can I assigned a post to multiple post status like it will be in 'publish' status and also a custom post status say 'hide' post status.

by this publish post count will remain same  and 'hide' post status can be hide from a loop.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I assigned a post to multiple post status like it will be in 'publish' status and also a custom post status say 'hide' post status.

This can be achieved by storing a post meta value. You can do stuff on the post based on this meta value.

> by this publish post count will remain same

The meta value won't change post count.

> 'hide' post status can be hide from a loop.

Do you mean that you don't want to show these posts in your site? You need to use meta query for that. In that case, see this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188940/23214

Answer (score 2):

You can't, really. [`post_status` is a column in the `*_posts` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts) and it isn't meant to have duplicate values.

[Use custom post meta instead](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).