# Set post beginning date and final date

Tags: posts, date

I'm developing a website that is like a Advertisements System.

I tried to use Post Expirator but it doesn't work the way we need.

It must set a BEGINNING DATE and EXPIRATE DATE.

Because will be A LOT of posts in website... client will send his sellers to sell ads so.. imagine how much ads the website will have. Thats because I also need the Beginning and Expiration date of each post.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using WordPress? or developing from scratch?

Comment: I'm using Wordpress

Comment: What's an ADS system? Or do you mean advertisements? All capital words tend to be accronyms, it's a tad confusing, if so, you're asking "How do I set an expiration date on a post?"

Comment: @TomJNowell Sorry. U'r right. Thats what I meant. We have a Advertisements system, and I need to know how do I set a beginning date and expiration date on a post. –

Comment: Your beginning date is the publish date, so you can eliminate that, and just ask for "How can I make a post expire at a certain date?"

Comment: There's a pretty full answer here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188940/94267