# Widget logic conditional widget

Tags: conditional-content

Is there any experience using widget logic, I want to display a widget on single custom post type with specific taxonomy. Tried using

```
is_tax(taxonomy_name) || is_single() && in_term(term_name).
```

Comment: I don't know what errors you are getting or what exactly your issue is, but `in_term()` according to my knowledge is invalid

Comment: Hi Pieter, the error I got is the sidebar widget not showing anything.

Comment: So, what the conditional should be for the cuatom taxonomy?  As per I knew, in_category is only for default

Comment: Do you mean a specific term, or for all terms under a specific taxonomy

Comment: Yes :), for example I have custom taxonomy with name resources, and child taxonomy of the resources is economic_news so I want to display the widget only on the single page of that taxonomy.

Comment: Same, is not working. May be my structure not too good. Maybe it helps if I am write down the situation. I have post type with name resource, on the resource have the main custom taxonomy (category) News, and news have the sub-taxonomy Statistical News. What I want is, on the single post of the Resource with Statistical News will show the specific Widget. Sorry for bad explanation

Comment: Did you change the values in my code. My code is not copy&paste ready, you need change the values yourself to your desired values. As I said, your terminology does not make sense, so I do not know what to use as the correct values. That you have to sort yourself

Comment: Hi, really thanks still help me: this my code on widget logic: global $post;
if ( $post->post_type == 'resource' // checks the post type of the post
     && is_single() // Checks if this is a single post
     && has_term( 'statistical-news', 'news', $post->ID ) // Check if post has specific term
) {
    // Do something if our condition is true
} and still no luck, I am really new using this widget logic

Comment: It should work. You have some other issue somewhere then. You are adding the code wrong, or your `$post` global is broken or you are using `query_posts` somewhere which is breaking the main query. Please, do not post code in comments, it is unreadable. File an [edit] and add code directly in your question

Comment: I see, yes maybe I have some other issue on that. Thanks

Comment: Hi All,

Finally is works well,I should answered here cause I can't post a answered (banned) the code I used is: `has_term( 'statistical-news', 'news' )`

Thanks All for the clue

Comment: No problem. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start, I must say that your terminology is quite confusing and plain wrong. You should take your time and read through [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) to this question: [Is There a Difference Between Taxonomies and Categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158206/is-there-a-difference-between-taxonomies-and-categories/158223#158223)

As I stated before, there is no `in_term()` function to check if a post has a specific term. There is however a [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function which accepts the term as first parameter and the taxonomy name as second parameter. So your condition should look like this: (*if this is for a specific post type outside the loop*)

```
global $post;
if ( $post->post_type == 'my_post_type' // checks the post type of the post
     && is_single() // Checks if this is a single post
     && has_term( 'term-name or id or slug', 'my_taxonomy', $post->ID ) // Check if post has specific term
) {
    // Do something if our condition is true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code:

```
if(has_tag( array( 'sharp', 'mild', 'extreme' ) ) && get_post_type()=="custom-post-type"){
}
```

The array value should be the term name which is stored in taxonomy.

You can directly pass the array in `has_tag()` function

Comment: `has_tag()` will not work. It works for the build in taxonomy `post_tag`, not a **custom taxonomy**

Comment: Also note, there is no `gas_tag()` function. I have corrected that

Comment: i have write for has_tag() function not gas_tag() function.

Comment: Whatever. Please see the revision history if you think I'm lying. As I said, I have **corrected** it

Comment: please check this 
if(in_array('tag-name',get_the_tags()) && get_post_type()=="custom-post-type")