# Wordpress get_posts by category

Tags: get-posts

I have the following bit of code:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'category'         => 7,
    'orderby'          => 'name',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'post_type'        => 'product'
);

$posts = get_posts($args);var_dump($posts);
```

This should return one post I know that is in the category, but it isn't. If I leave out the 'category'-argument, I get all the products, so I know this should normally work. If I change the category to 1 and take out my custom post type (product), I get my default posts.

I can't see what's wrong with this. Can anyone spot what the problem is?

Comment: Shouldn't it be taxonomy name instead of category?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I got this off the codex-page of wordpress, which seems to support my approach, but still, it doesn't work: "Note: The category parameter needs to be the ID of the category, and not the category name."

Comment: The minus1 (-1) in posts_per_page will show ALL posts and as soon you leave out the CPT wp will "fall back" at the regular posts as you already found out yourself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In all probability you are using a custom taxonomy, and not the build-in `category` taxonomy. If this is the case, then the category parameters won't work. You will need a [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to query posts from a specific term. (*Remember, `get_posts` uses `WP_Query`, so you can pass any parameter from `WP_Query` to `get_posts`*)

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'my_custom_taxonomy',
            'terms' => 7,
            'include_children' => false // Remove if you need posts from term 7 child terms
        ],
    ],
    // Rest of your arguments
];
```

### ADDITIONAL RESOURCES

- [What is the difference between custom taxonomies and categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545)

Answer (score 8):

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();?>


    </ul>
```

May [this will](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) help You.

Thanks

Comment: Some explanation will be great.

Comment: From which 'post_type' he will get now the link**s**, 5 in your case? Imho he wants the *content* of *products*(as I understand a CPT) and nothing from the regular posts.

Comment: pass your category id in arguments and from regular post you will get 5 posts.

Comment: Read his question please, I am not always right but in this case he wants 'something' from a Custom Post Type with the name Product.

Comment: Charles is right in this case. I know how to get the data once I have my posts. The problem was that I wasn't getting the my custom posts :)

Comment: @Rohitgilbile how to include featured image inside foreach loop ?