# Get posts from specific taxonomy term

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, terms, get-posts, slug

I have nhl news website and I have taxonomy for each season (ex 2014-15)

Taxonomy in functions:

```
function wptp_register_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( 'season', 'post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'              => 'Seasons',
                'singular_name'     => 'Season',
                'search_items'      => 'Search Season',
                'all_items'         => 'All Season',
                'edit_item'         => 'Edit Season',
                'update_item'       => 'Update',
                'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Season',
                'new_item_name'     => 'New Season',
                'menu_name'         => 'Seasons',
            ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'sort' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'season' ),
            'show_admin_column' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wptp_register_taxonomy' );
```

I assign all posts from 'news' category into different terms for each season ex:20132014 20142015

I create taxonomy term query so when I go to this url `localhost/nhl/news/?season=20132014` shows me posts from this specific season instead of going here `localhost/nfl/season/20132014`

What I am trying to do?

To get posts from this term for ex 20142015 (current real season) and show them in the category news `localhost/nhl/news` without show all posts from all terms and without using url query **?season=(term)**

localhost/**nhl<--folder name in wamp**/**news<--categoryname**/

Thank you

Comment: remove the `'operator' => 'IN'` and try

Comment: @Karun didn't work still I see all posts from all seasons. Did you understand what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Your terminology is really confusing. You say you have a taxonomy per season, then season cannot be the taxonomy in your tax_query. Also, I cannot see why you are using `pre_get_posts` here. This is stuffing everything around. You can simply remove that. How are your `season` and other taxonomies joined. As far as I can see you are only querying the `season` taxonomy. Please properly explain what you want. I say again, your terminology makes no sense at all, it is really confusing and hard to understand

Comment: Please go and read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) then come back and rephrase your question. You still just show the `season` taxonomy but nothing about the other taxonomies. Are these even taxonomies?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think the use of `pre_get_posts` is what it is needed to do what the OP wants to do. Please, @LinekereDe don't remove that piece of code so we can see what you have tried so far, but edit the question to provide more accurate inforamtion.

Comment: @cybmeta The terminology is totally confusing here. `http://localhost/nhl/news/` will just 404 in my opinion if news is what I think it is, but, again, what the hell is `news`. But apart from that, why do you need to run the same tax query on all taxonomy pages. You will get the same result on all pages. It just does not make sense

Comment: @PieterGoosen Sorry I am confused removed pre_get_posts and still working and rewrote the question again

Comment: Glad I'm not the only confused soul here. Please explain this line: *I have taxonomy for each season (ex 2014-15)* If `season` is a taxonomy, and `20142015` is a taxonomy, how are they linked. I can understand now that apparently `news` is a term under the taxonomy `season`. The big mystery remains, how is `20142015` created, where do get that from, how is it linked the `season` taxonomy.

Comment: @PieterGoosen 20142015 is not taxonomy is the term of taxonomy season

Comment: Right, now we are getting somewhere :-). You should update your post with that info as well. So, now, `news` is also a term under the taxonomy `season`. How does `news` and `20142015` interact, what is their relation to one another.

Comment: @PieterGoosen  news is the **category** that I assign all posts into different terms for each season ex:20132014 20142015. But as I told you above I create taxonomy term query so when I go to this url http://localhost/nhl/news/?season=20132014 shows me posts from this specific season instead of going here http://localhost/nfl/season/20132014. What I want is to get posts from this term 20142015 (current real season) and show them in the category news http://localhost/nhl/news without show all posts from all terms and without using url query **?season=(term)**

Comment: Ok, that is starting to make sense now. One last question, if you have `?season={$term}` in the URL, how do you filter the posts to just show posts from that specific term. Please update your question with this info

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks for your help and patience :) Can you please explain what do you mean _"how do you filter the posts to just show posts from that specific term"_

Comment: You said: *when I go to this url localhost/nhl/news/?season=20132014 shows me posts from this specific season*. How are you doing it, how are you filtering your posts to just show posts from `20132014`. You are really really overcomplicating your structures here from the look of things. By default, if you go to `localhost/nhl/news/?season=20132014` or `localhost/nhl/news/` or `localhost/nhl/news/?bull=shit`, you will still only get all posts from term `news` regardless

Comment: You must have some sort of filtering to only show posts from `shit` when your URL is `localhost/nhl/news/?bull=shit`

Comment: @PieterGoosen I dont see any filtering in my code the only thing that I have is the above wptp_register_taxonomy() by default shows me what I told you

Comment: Please post the code of the template you are using when you visit `localhost/nhl/news/`. There **has to be** some kind of filtering system to show specific posts according to the URL. `season` is not a default build in query variable, so `WP_Query` will ignore it. `season` needs to be registered so that Wordpress can recognise it, that value then needs to be passed to `WP_Query` in some form to get the correct posts according to the value of `season` in the URL

Comment: @PieterGoosen I tried the above function into clean Twenty Fifteen without filtering or something and is working

Comment: Then you have plugin doing it.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Finally disable this plugin and is not working _WP No Category Base - WPML compatible Desc:Removes '/category' from your category permalinks. WPML compatible._ but this is related to the solution that I need?

Comment: YEAH!!! Now my question is, why do you not use the default structures. We've been in so many circles here because of a stupid plugin filtering our results

Comment: You will first need to sort your structures properly

Comment: @PieterGoosen Using the plugin to remove "/category/" from permalinks now why are you telling me about default structures etc?

Answer (score -1):

this code will display the post from all taxonomy in wordpress:

```
$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'season',
    'pad_counts'               => false 

    ); 
$taxonomy = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $taxonomy as $tax ) {

$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'season',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $tax->term_id,
            )
        )
    )
);

 print_r( $posts_array ); 
}
```

if you want to display specific post then pass below codes:

```
$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'season',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => 2, // taxonomy id
            )
        )
    )
);

 print_r( $posts_array );
```

Comment: You are mixing up terms, categories and taxonomies into one disaster. The blind is leading the blind here, sorry if I offended you, but this is what is happening at the moment