# Category archives

Tags: categories, archives

According to the [WordPress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates#What_Template_File_is_Used.3F), to show a Category archive you simply need to create a file with the right file name

i.e.

1. category-slug.php
2. category-ID.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php

However what I'm finding is that it's simply serving up option 4 (i.e. archive.php).

Here's my Categories page:

[image]

How do I fix this or investigate further to figure out the problem?

Comment: You are most probably making use of a custom taxonomy in which case you need to use the taxonomy archive template hierarchy ;-)

Comment: Is creating a new Category called 'news' mean I'm using a custom taxonomy? I had a read of https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies but, by the end, still couldn't work out if I was or wasn't.

Comment: First read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) about the difference between categories, term and taxonomies :-)

Comment: Take a snapshot of your backend regarding this and send the pic

Comment: This is normal category. If the hierarchy in your question does not work, then you have an issue with a custom filter, or using `query_posts` or have an issue with a custom rewrite rule