# Also show terms that are related to draft and pending posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-status

Im using `wp_dropdown_categories` to output terms in dropdown menu but it only shows terms that are related to **published** posts.

I wonder if there's a way / hack to include terms that are related to **pending** and **draft** posts?

---

[Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) doesn't say anything about that, also searching the web didn't give any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are meaning terms and not taxonomies. For clarity on which is which, see my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545)

In general, terms without published posts are considered empty and are hidden in functions like `wp_dropdown_categories()`.Setting `hide_empty` to `0` (*`false`*) in your arguments will display all terms, even the "empty" ones.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, I meant terms. I was hoping there was some kind of undocumented argument or something.. It sucks then, I don't want to show empty dropdown, I also don't need to show every single one.

Comment: 7 years later and I also cannot find a good solution for this, so I had to write my own taxonomy dropdown function. Here it is if anyone wants to use it: https://gist.github.com/gavin310/833be65ec43a10abfe3b7df8aa739d1e