# WP Query - filtering terms with regex

Tags: wp-query, database, taxonomy

is there a possibility of filtering posts by terms using regexp? My code doesn't quite seem to work.

```
$tax[] = [
    'taxonomy'  => 'tax_name',
    'field'     => 'name',
    'terms'     => $name,
    'operator'  => 'REGEXP',
];
```

The `$tax` variable is then properly added to `WP_Query` args.

Comment: I don't get your question here, why do you need to match taxonomy names with regex

Comment: I'm doing a custom search and I need to match the post taxonomy with user input with regex.

Comment: Are you talking about ***taxonomies*** or ***terms*** here. Please read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) first

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but give it a go.  First get a list of the term names in the taxonomy.  Then filter the returned array of names against your regex.  Then use that filtered array of names for your WP query.

```
// assumes these assignments:
//
// $taxonomy - the taxonomy name you are querying against
// $regex - the regex to match the term names against

// First get all the terms that have posts:

$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'fields' => 'names', // return an array of term names
) );

$filtered_terms = preg_grep($regex, $terms);

// when you use this, expand $args with other relevant arguments for your query, such as post type:

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $filtered_terms,
        ),
    ),
)

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Then run your loop
```